# Nested menu bar in angular 2 with material design

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng, angular-material2

I am developing a web app in angular2. I am looking for a nested menu bar in material design.

I found a component in primeNG library ([Tiered Menu](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tieredmenu)) that matches my requirement. But the issue here is that it is not in material design.

Can anyone suggest a good library or component for my problem?

Or is there any way I can use primeNG component and make it material?

Comment: You can overwrite all styles of the menu to make it material...